# Why does SQL Server parameter limit get hit for string IDs but not auto-incrementing IDs?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'm building a software project (PHP & Laravel) that uses an ORM to generate SQL. I'm hitting an SQL Server (2019) parameter limit of 2100 (using `where in`) but only when using string IDs and not when using integer IDs. Why would this be the case? I would expect to hit the 2100 limit regardless of the parameter type.

Example query:

```sql
select
  *
from
  [users]
where
  [users].[id] in (
    'adhc05',
    'yizj19',
    'rues03',
    'usaw47',
    'ddta80',
    'tdls80',
    'vfjf76',
    'sohy36',
    'ucxm31',
    'zwzo73',
    etc...
  )
order by
  [users].[id] asc
```

> SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 2101. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.

The following query does not hit the parameter limit, even though it's selecting more than 2100 users:

```sql
select
  *
from
  [users]
where
  [users].[id] in (
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    etc...
  )
order by
  [users].[id] asc
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I'd be looking at the ORM and either breaking up into batches or using a temp table perhaps ...

Comment: Yes, I plan to chunk the query but I'm just confused as to why I'm only hitting the limit with string keys?

Comment: because it's longer with strings?! ? :)  I suspect you are hitting a different limit with strings, namely the total query length ?

Comment: I might have just found the answer while Googling some more. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/100k-rows-with-eager-loading-result-in-too-many-sql-parameters

You we're right, the ORM is doing some magic with int keys.

Comment: Or a Table Valued Parameter. Anything over about 50 parameters is insane.

Comment: @Charlieface: ORMs often emit insane amounts of params.

Comment: @MitchWheat Unfortunately. But most can be made to use TVPs. Laravel seems to support JSON so that is another option.

Comment: *a guess:* the total string length of 2100 strings (with their apostrophes) is greater than 2100 simple integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be that Laravel's ORM no longer parameterizes integer keys which is why I wasn't hitting the parameter limit there.

Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26434